# Как задать шрифт в java?

Tags: java, шрифты

Не могли бы вы мне помочь с заданием шрифта в java?

Я пытаюсь задать шрифт но вылетает такая ошибка: java.io.IOException: Can't read ..\fonts\Roboto-light.ttf

вот код:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        init();
    }

    private static void init(){
        Text.init();
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        try {
            ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("../fonts/Roboto-light.ttf")));
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы задали относительный путь к файлу, но где папка `.`, неясно. Лучше положить его в resources/fonts и получать через getResources:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
InputStream is = ИмяЭтогоКласса.class.getResourceAsStream("fonts/Roboto-light.ttf");
try {
    ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is));
} catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!